# How to create ethernet port from fpga digital input-output pins?

Tags: fpga, ethernet, zynq

I have zynq with carrier board. This board has a ethernet port, but I need two ports. Can I create new ethernet port with fpga IO pins. Is it possible or do have any different idea about that?
My board is Picozed FMC Carrier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short: No!

An ethernet interface is a special type of analogue interface with lots and lots of special circuitry on it. You can NOT get the right behavior with a digital interface.

If your FPGA has a USB port you might try to add a USB <=> Ethernet converter chip to get a second Ethernet port. (like all the old Raspberry-Pi's have).

Comment: Does USB has both analogue and digital pin? (5V,0V,TX and RX) Like USB <=> Ethernet converter, can I create w,th 5V,GND and IO pins?

Comment: The Zynq has SERDER channels which can be programmed to work as USB3, Check your zynq datasheet for details.